# Disabled add-in/ Manage add-in won't load

Tags: outlook-addin, add-in, outlook-web-app

I'm new into developing add-ins and I wonder why does the Manage Add-in in Settings in OWA says "There was a problem loading your options. Please try again". I don't quite understand. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to reset OWA User configuration:

1. Download MFCMapi tool: http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/
2. Before performing any step, please make sure that Outlook client is not running on that machine and user is not connected to OWA.
3. Open MFCMapi on the machine used by the user – we will need the Outlook profile to open the store with this tool.
4. Go to Tools -> Options -> and tick the boxes with Use the MDB_ONLINE flag and Use the MAPI_NO_CACHE flag to make sure that the task is done on the store, and not on the local OST file.
5. Then go to the main menu Session -> Logon… -> and chose the Outlook profile used by user
6. Select the store for user's mailbox from the list and double-click to open the store. On the new page that is open, right click on the Root Container and chose Open associated contents table
7. On the Hidden Contents table tab, arrange the columns header and scroll to the right until you can see the Message Class details for each entry.
8. Right Click on the Message Class -> Delete message -> Permanent deletion (delete to deleted items retention if supported) and hit OK (For entries bellow)
9. Please repeat the above deletion steps for the below 3 entries:

   ```
      IPM.Configuration.Suite.Storage
      IPM.Configuration.OWA.UserOptions
      IPM.Configuration.Agregated.OWAUserConfiguration
   ```
10. Once the above steps were performed, close the MFCMapi using the X button on the right top corner – no need for specific logoff.
11. Now try to login to OWA and test if OWA options can be changed or no error messages are shown.

Also you may find the [Most of Options Cannot Displayed in OWA](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/978e901a-1be1-4268-aa06-f09b64a81727/most-of-options-cannot-displayed-in-owa?forum=Exch2016Adm) forum thread helpful.